# Coefficient and Addition Formula

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, trigonometry, algebra

If I type:

```
Coefficient[Cos[x + b], Cos[x]]
```

I get zero.

But I would like Mathematica to apply:

$$\cos(x+b)=\cos x\cos b-\sin x\sin b$$

Therefore the coefficient of $\cos x$ should be $\cos b$.

How do I fix this?

**Edit:**

The solution `Coefficient[TrigExpand@f[x],Cos[x]]` has been proposed, but this wouldn't work for expressions like $\sin(a+3x)$, in fact:

```
In[84]:= TrigExpand@Sin[a + 3 x]

Out[84]= Cos[x]^3 Sin[a] + 3 Cos[a] Cos[x]^2 Sin[x] - 
         3 Cos[x] Sin[a] Sin[x]^2 - Cos[a] Sin[x]^3
```

And therefore this would give me a wrong coefficient:

```
In[86]:= Coefficient[TrigExpand@Sin[a + 3 x], Cos[x]]

Out[86]= -3 Sin[a] Sin[x]^2
```

Because $\sin x$ is not a constant, and for what I am concerned with, it cannot be the coefficient of $\cos x$. Therefore, for all the expressions of the type $\cos(n x+ a)$ I am expecting to find zero, except when $n=1$.

Comment: This is not exactly what I think would work, I will explain it in the edit :)

Comment: @Kuba It would be zero.

Comment: @Kuba for all the expressions of the type $\cos(nx+a)$ I am expecting to find zero, except when $n=1$

Comment: These expressions do not have unique representations as polynomials in `{sin(x),cos(x)}`. This of course is due to the fundamental trig identity. A possible way around this would be to obtain coefficients in terms of both trig terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is another approach:

```
ClearAll[findCoeff];
findCoeff[expr_, termToIsolate_] := Module[{findCoeffIn},
  findCoeffIn[termToIsolate] = 1;
  findCoeffIn[exprIn_Plus, OptionsPattern[]] := findCoeffIn /@ exprIn;
  findCoeffIn[Times[lterms___, termToIsolate, rterms___]] := 
   If[FreeQ[#, x], #, 0] &@Times[lterms, rterms];
  findCoeffIn[exprIn : (Cos[_] | Sin[_] | Tan[_] | Cot[_]), 
    OptionsPattern[]] := findCoeffIn[TrigExpand[exprIn]];
  findCoeffIn[_] := 0;
  findCoeffIn[expr]
  ]
```

This seems to work on all the cases that I tried.
Use it like this:

```
In[1]:= findCoeff[Cos[2 x] + Cos[x + a] + 2, Cos[x]]
Out[1]= Cos[a]

In[2]:= findCoeff[2 Cos[x], Cos[x]]
Out[2]= 2

In[3]:= findCoeff[Cos[x + a] + Sin[2 x] + Cos[x], Cos[x]]
Out[3]= 1 + Cos[a]

In[4]:= findCoeff[Cos[2 x], Cos[2 x]]
Out[4]= 1
```

Something like `findCoeff[Sin[2 x+a],Cos[2 x]]` will still not work as you want it to, though. One probably has to fiddle with `FourierCosCoefficient` to do that.
In fact, I'm not even sure that the problem is well stated: consider for example `Sin[2x]`. How should it expand? `FourierCosCoefficient[Sin[2 x],x ,1]` gives the answer $8/3\pi$, while `findCoeff[Sin[2 x],Cos[x]]` gives 0. While the former result answers a well defined question, what exactly are the rules according to which you want the latter result?

## Old

Here is a slightly improved version of [Kuba's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101504/27539):

```
Options[findCoeff] = {termToIsolate -> Cos[x], 
   independentVariable -> x};
findCoeff[expr_, OptionsPattern[]] := Total@Cases[
    TrigExpand[expr],
    cl___ OptionValue@termToIsolate cr___ :> 
     cl cr /; FreeQ[cl cr, OptionValue@independentVariable]
    ] /. {} -> 0
```

Examples:

```
In[1]:= findCoeff[Sin[2 x] + 2 Cos[x] + Cos[x + a]]

Out[1]= 2 + Cos[a]

In[2]:= findCoeff[Cos[y + x] + Sin[x], termToIsolate -> Cos[y], 
 independentVariable -> y]

Out[2]= Cos[x]
```

I'm not sure it would work on more complicated cases though.

Comment: `findCoeff[Sin[2 x] 2 + 1 Cos[x]]` gives `0`

Comment: Also, I cannot choose `Sin[2 x]` as a `termToIsolate`

Comment: @usumdelphini see the edit

Answer (score 2):

Does it fit your needs?

```
Cases[
  TrigExpand@Sin[a + x],
  Cos[x] coeff__ :> coeff /; FreeQ[coeff, x]
  ] /. {} -> 0
```

---

**Old:**

Not sure if I got your point in general but this should do: (*no it shouldn't really*)

```
FourierCosCoefficient[Cos[x + b], x, 1]

FourierCosCoefficient[Sin[a + 3 x], x, 1]
```

> ```
> Cos[b]
>
> 0
> ```

Comment: This does not seem to work for `Cases[TrigExpand@(Sin[a + x] + Sin[2 x]), 
  Cos[x] coeff__ :> coeff /; FreeQ[coeff, x]] /. {} -> 0`

Comment: @usumdelphini it gives `Sin[a]` which is expected since there is `Cos[x] Sin[a]`, if not define what is coefficient.

Comment: That's true, sorry. But it does not work for `Cases[TrigExpand@(((-C1 + C2) Sin[x])/a), 
   Sin[x] coeff__ :> coeff /; FreeQ[coeff, x]] /. {} -> 0`

Comment: @usumdelphini modifying the code like this `Cases[
  TrigExpand[Sin[a + x] + Sin[2 x]],
  cl___ Cos[x] cr___ :> cl cr /; FreeQ[cl cr, x]
  ] /. {} -> 0` works in your cases. It would probably fail in more complicated ones, though

Comment: @glS This is very helpful, thanks. Is there a way to use Cos[2x] as a variable though? I mean, these cases still give wrong results: `Cases[TrigExpand[Cos[2 \[Phi]]], 
  cl___ Cos[2 \[Phi]] cr___ :> cl cr /; FreeQ[cl cr, x]] /. {} -> 0`

Comment: @usumdelphini if you expand `Cos[2x]` you cannot then ask to isolate `Cos[2x]`. You should probably explain better what exactly do you need this function for

Comment: @glS That is true, but I would like to be able to change options and isolate `Cos[2 x]` instead. It would be great to have also that freedom. But your answer is already very helpful indeed.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Ok, now this answer is almost the same as Kuba's...

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I think Kuba's answer is preferable, but you could also do this:

```
coeff[expr_, var_] := Boole[FreeQ[#,x]]*#&@
  Coefficient[TrigExpand@expr, var]
```

Then,

```
coeff[Sin[a + 3 x], Cos[x]]
```

> 0

and

```
coeff[Cos[a+x],Cos[x]]
```

> Cos[a]

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to extend it to the use of $\sin(2 x)$ as `var` for example?

Comment: Now it does not work for `coeff[Cos[a + x] + Sin[2 x], Cos[x]]`